# Is conformal equivalence the same as topological equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces, surfaces, conformal-geometry

Is it true that if I take two surfaces that are topologically equivalent, I can find a conformal mapping between them?

Comment: No. Consider $\mathbb{C}$ and the unit disk.

Comment: Ok, so is there some other way to characterize an equivalence class of conformally equivalent surfaces? For example, in the topological case we can use the genus.

Comment: According to [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Non-orientable_surfaces), genus is not sufficient for the topological case. $\;$

Comment: Riemann was aware of this problem. In general for a closed surface of genus g there are 6g - 6  parameters for a closed surface and 6g - 6 + n  when the surface is open and we have n boundary components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest nontrivial case is  an open cylinder. Each of these is conformally equivalent to a circular annulus $\{z: r<|z|<R\}$, and two such annuli are conformally equivalent iff they have the same ratio $R/r$. In other words, annuli are classified by one real parameter, [conformal modulus](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Modulus_of_an_annulus).

The  case of torus was discussed in [conformally equivalent flat tori](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215916/).

In general, the key term is the *moduli space* of a surface. As Alan noted in comments, its dimension can be expressed in terms of the genus and the number of boundary components. The formidable [to me] [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space) suggests that the subject is not an easy one to enter, while the MathOverflow discussion [Intuition behind moduli space of curves](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7787) attempts to give some   low-tech insights.